# Can no longer use anonymous classes after upgrading to version 1.0.0

Tags: scala.js

I have just tried upgrading my project from version 0.6.x to the latest version 1.0.0-M8 and am now getting a string of compilation errors anywhere I had declared an anonymous class.

So for example if I did:

```
def myFunc(x: Int) = new { ... }

val x = new SomeAbstractClass(p1, p2) { ... }
```

I get the compilation errors:

> Error: type WasPublicBeforeTyper is not a member of package
>   scala.scalajs.js.annotation   def myFunc(node: Node) = new {
>
> Error: type WasPublicBeforeTyper is not a member of package
>   scala.scalajs.js.annotation
>                 form = new SomeAbstractClass(p1, p2) {

Comment: Note. I tried version M1 and its also a problem there.

Comment: It seems the scalajs-library jar is not on the classpath of your project. Check that you do not erase it with something like using `libraryDependencies :=` (instead of `++=`).